# Leaflet or SVG Element with ion-scroll to create an image map in Ionic?

Tags: svg, ionic-framework, leaflet

I want to create a map in an Ionic app based on a jpeg/png image with markers on it.

Example of what I want is in the ios 'Explore 9/11' app:

[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, what did your research turn up? What have you tryed? What didn't work? What problems did it give? Any errors? This is by far not a question which adheres to Stackoverflow standards. Please give this a good and thorough read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and afterwards edit your question

Comment: I think your right, sorry. I'll do some more research.